# How to backup Backup Exec 2010 job setup, job history, catalogs etc

Tags: backupexec, symantec

How do you make a backup of the job setup, job history, catalogs etc for Symantec Backup Exec 2010 Small Business Server edition and how do you restore them again afterwards? Do I just need to backup the SQL database or is there more involved?

As a diagnostic step I need to uninstall Backup Exec but I want to restore the job history etc when I install it again afterwards. The server is running Small Business Server 2008.

Comment: There's more involved; you can find it all here though: http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH67768